# Using PSD with HTML & Mail Chimp to create an enquiry form

Tags: html, email, mailchimp, psd

I have been looking everywhere for this answer and I am struggling to find one. 
I have a couple of websites and I would like to implement a PSD file I have created for an enquiry form, with HTML that is going to link to Mail Chimp. 
Would I need to add the images to the HTML some how?
Does any one know any forums that I could look at?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: ummm - whats that thing with two o's in on that internet thingamy - are yes why not look on google - I assume you have some kind internet access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is to save the images into a folder as jpg's, png's, gif's etc, along with a html file (I use Dreamweaver) and then you zip up all your files once the html file is complete and then upload the zipped files straight to mailchimp.

that's how I got about using mailchimp

Comment: ah right okay, where did you upload them all to? and do you need an advanced account

Comment: You can create a free account with an email address you have and upload the zipped files straight to mailchimp when you create an new campaign. I'm not sure how many emails you can send out with a free account but what I used it for is sending a test email to myself which basically hosts the files on mailchimp and it lets you forward the mail onto other recipients